# Where would you implement sticky session / session persistence / distributed session in your stack?

Tags: session, jboss, load, apache, sticky

If you had to implement sticky session / session persistence / distributed sessions, where would you do it?

The load balancer where the traffic comes in from the outside
The apache instance where the load balancer connects to 
or
The jboss instance (two of them) on each server?

I have an application that is being load balanced to 6 servers. Each server has an httpd process and is using balancer manager to balance load between two JBOSS instances on each machine (so 12 total). Would you implement sticky session / session persistence / distributed session support at the application (JBOSS) level or load balancer level?